# TestScheduler does not work (Kotlin + RxJava2 + mockito)

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, rx-java2

I wanted to write a unit test that will verify `callInit` method below. However, I've got null pointer exception where the line holds `subscribe(`. My question is how do I verify onnext and onerror conditions in a method such below?

```
override fun callInit() {
    val requestInit = RequestInit(os = "android", osVersion = deviceUtil.osVersion(),
        appVersion = deviceUtil.apiVersion())
    compositeDisposable.add(
        interactor.getInit(requestInit)
            .subscribe(
                {
                  view.hideProgress()
                  this.commercialLink = it.commercialLink
                  view.updateScreen()
                },
                { error -> view.onError(error) }
            )
    )
}
```

Test method:

```
 @Test
 fun should_update_commerciallink_AND_updateScreen_when_callInit() {
    val request = RequestInit("android", "version", "osversion")
    val responseInit = ResponseInit(false, false,
        "updatelink", "message", "useragreement", "commerciallink")

    whenever(deviceUtil.osVersion()).thenReturn("version")
    whenever(deviceUtil.apiVersion()).thenReturn("apiversion")
    whenever(interactor.getInit(request)).thenReturn(Observable.just(responseInit))

    presenter.callInit()

    testScheduler.triggerActions()
    verify(view).hideProgress()
    verify(view).updateScreen()
}
```

EDIT

```
class SplashInteractor(private val initService: InitService,
    private val schedulerProvider: SchedulerProvider) : SplashContract.Interactor {

  override fun getInit(requestInit: SplashRequest.Init): Observable<SplashResponse.Init> {
    return initService.init(requestInit)
        .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
        .flatMap(funcErrorCheckAndTransform())
        .flatMap(funcVersionControl())
        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
  }

  override fun downloadCommercialVideo(commercialLink: String): Observable<File> {
    return initService.downloadCommercialLink(commercialLink)
        .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
        .flatMap(funcDownload(commercialLink))
        .observeOn(schedulerProvider.ui())
  }
}
```

presenter test

```
  @Before
  fun setUp() {
    testScheduler = TestScheduler()
    interactor = SplashInteractor(initService, TestSchedulerProvider(testScheduler))

    presenter = SplashPresenter(contract, interactor, uriWrapper, compositeDisposable,
        cache, fileUtil, deviceUtil)
    spyPresenter = Mockito.spy(presenter)

  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the last `whenever` statement, because it is checking the condition that the `request` parameter is passed. You should just check that the parameter is a `RequestInit`, something like `Mockito.isA(RequestInit.class)` as parameter.
So in java it would be: `when(interactor.getInit(isA(RequestInit.class))).thenReturn(Observable.just(responseInit))`

Comment: Can you show how you set `TestScheduler` in tests? And looking to your code and test you don't need it

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in one of `whenever` statements:

```
    whenever(deviceUtil.apiVersion()).thenReturn("apiversion")
```

You have instructed to return "apiversion", but the actual `request` is declared in slightly another way:

```
    val request = RequestInit(..., ..., "osversion")
```

These two string are **not** equal, thus Mockito cannot return the `Observable` that you are expecting.

Change `"osversion"` to `"apiversion"`.

Comment: its not even close, there is something different. It does not mock interactor class as I understand, above I put the other necessary codes.